# Apache URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying and failing to get a URL rewrite working, firstly I'm doing it in the vhost declaration, is that right?

What I'm trying to do is take any URL which has;

```
view.php?id=[a 1 or multidigit number]
```

and rewrite it to

```
view.php?id=[number]&section=1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for looking.

Okay, so I tried the suggestion below (thanks for that) and now have this in my vhost file but still no effect;

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ########
    DocumentRoot "########"
    ServerName ########
    ErrorLog "logs\########.log
        <Directory "########">
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            AcceptPathInfo on
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
        </Directory>
        <Location />
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule ^/view.php?id=([0-9]*)$ /view.php?id=$1&section=1 [R]
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a bit more, if a URL already has &section=[a number] attached to it, I don't want to rewrite that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !section=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/view\.php$ /view.php?section=1 [R,QSA]
```

The first RewriteCond looks at the query string for an id. The second ensures there isn't already a section in the query string. [R,QSA] specifies that the redirect preserves existing query parameters.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be having any effect, added a bit more above.

Comment: My apologies. I have updated this with a working redirect.